# How to unload the package in TCL?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I loaded a package first:

```
package require Tktable
```

then i wanted to unload this package. I searched some info, and used "package ifneeded" to get the library path. I tried as below:

```
unload $path Tktable
```

but i got error message "cannot be unloaded under a trusted interpreter". How to unload a package?

Comment: Why do you need to unload it? Did you try `package forget`?

Comment: After i loaded this package, some command of my platform were overwrote by this package. So i want to unload it in some speciaI situation. I've tried package forget, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Unless special precautions are taken, commands overwritten by other commands don't come back even if you excise the package they came in. You could try putting your commands in a namespace to preserve them.

Comment: May i ask how to preserve  the commands? i tried like this: namespace eval foo  {package require Tkable}, but the command was still overwrote...

Comment: A package that puts commands in the global namespace will most likely do so even if you require it in a namespace eval. What you can control is where your own commands are. If you create them in a namespace of your own,  no package will overwrite them. To preserve occasional commands, you could also use rename before requiring the package.

Comment: If the command `foo` is being overwritten by the package when you require it, then do `rename foo _foo` beforehand, and access it with `_foo`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Most packages do not support unloading at all. (Specifically, Tktable does not; it doesn't define either a `Tktable_Unload` function or a `Tktable_SafeUnload` function in its public C API.) Unloading is rare as it requires the author of the C code to take special care to ensure that it is possible at all, and most of the time programmers have other higher-priority concerns.
2. Unloading is disabled in safe interpreters, as it is considered to be an insecure operation. (`load` is also not supported, but is often profiled in restricted fashion by the parent master interpreter, such as via `package require` doing clever things behind the scenes.)
3. If the problem is that some package is interfering with your code (as seems to be the case from your comments), put *your* code in a namespace. There's often an easy way to pick the namespace name, typically the name of your application or library works fine. If you're wanting to call your code the same thing as someone else's and their code is more well-known than yours, that's going to cause you trouble anyway.